# Javascript function to get the absolute difference between two numbers

Tags: javascript, function

I want a Simple Javascript function to get the difference between two numbers in such a way that `foo(2, 3)` and `foo(3,2`) will return the same difference 1.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

```
var difference = function (a, b) { return Math.abs(a - b); }
```

Comment: Alternative (and more used syntax): `function diff(a,b){return Math.abs(a-b);}`

Best and simples solution.

Comment: .. and then `foo = difference`, to be complete :)

Comment: Why putting the function in a var ?

Comment: Clement Herreman: it's a different story. this "varing" is not necessary at all, i just wanted to provide a pure solution (properly define the function in the actual scope)

Answer (score 51):

Here is a simple function

```
function diff (num1, num2) {
  if (num1 > num2) {
    return num1 - num2
  } else {
    return num2 - num1
  }
}
```

And as a shorter, one-line, single-argument, ternary-using arrow function

```
function diff (a, b) => a > b ? a - b : b - a
```

Comment: @Jake, I completely agree :) I was giving that as an example to Tom who claimed that using Math.abs() gives wrong results when using negative numbers. But since 8 is the correct answer, it shows Math.abs() gives the correct answer.

Comment: I did the performance test and it is not faster than Math.abs(), it is basically the same. Use the solution you want, it makes no difference.

Comment: this is a solution for any signed number. `Math.abs()` is not a complete solution.

Comment: @ChrisDeacy, Niels was explaining to Tom how solutions using `Math.abs()` still return the right answers, like `8` for `3, -5`. He was making the exact same point you're trying to make...

Answer (score 26):

Seems odd to define a whole new function just to not have to put a minus sign instead of a comma when you call it:

```
Math.abs(a - b);
```

vs

```
difference(a, b);
```

(with difference calling another function you defined to call that returns the output of the first code example). I'd just use the built in abs method on the Math object.

Comment: I agree. I like abstracting things out for reusability, but in cases where it's simple or just built in things, there's no real benefit.

Answer (score 10):

It means you want to return absolute value.

```
function foo(num1 , num2) {
   return Math.abs(num1-num2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function difference(n, m){
    return Math.abs(n - m)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't get how this is possible on such a seemingly common question, but all the answers I found here are wrong in certain cases.

If both numbers are on the same side of zero then the accepted answer is right, but if the numbers are not on the same side of zero, then their absolute values must be added, not subtracted.

```
function diff( x, y ) {

    if ( Math.sign( x ) === Math.sign( y ) ) {

        return Math.abs( x - y );

    } else {

        return Math.abs( x ) + Math.abs( y );

    };

};

diff( 2, 2 ) // 0
diff( -2, -2 ) // 0
diff( -2, 2 ) // 4
diff( 2, -2 ) // 4
```

Solution on math.stackexchange.com : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1893992

Comment: This is unnecessary. `Math.abs((-2) - 2)` still yields correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `TypeScript`, if anyone interested:

```
public getDiff(value: number, oldValue: number) {
    return value > oldValue ? value - oldValue : oldValue - value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

defining four functions I made a little benchmark, surprisingly

```js
fn1 = (a,b)=>(a>b)?a-b:b-a;
fn2 = (a,b)=>{let c= a-b;return c>0?c:-c;}
fn3 = (a,b)=>Math.abs(a-b)
fn4 = (a,b)=>Math.max(a-b, b-a)


for(let fn of [ fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4])
 executionTime(()=>{console.log(fn);for(let i=0;i<1_000_000;i++)fn(500_000,i)})
 

 
 
 
 function executionTime(cb){//calculate performance
    const t0 = performance.now();
    cb();
    const t1 = performance.now();
    console.log(`cb took ${t1 - t0} milliseconds.`);
}
```

Here are the results for 1million iterations:

1. cb took 11.129999998956919 milliseconds.
2. cb took 53.420000011101365 milliseconds.
3. cb took 47.40000003948808 milliseconds.
4. cb took 48.20000007748604 milliseconds.

But unfortunalelly those are false results, I mean executing one by one gave on the console resulting:

1. 6.9ms  11.7    7.0   4.4
2. 7.5ms   4.4    6.4   4.5
3. 7.8ms   5.1    6.2   6.8
4. 3.9ms   6.3    5.2   5.2

I think while looping, after each iteration garbage is collecting while other functions doing their bests. While executing each one by one, fn2 came second, while using extra variable( vm is optimizing with register ? ) .

Answer (score 0):

If you work with floating numbers - the pitfall of the answers above is the math.

For example

```
> 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004
```

You can use a hack like this in your calculations:

```
total = parseFloat((total + parseFloat(difference.toFixed(2))).toFixed(2))
```